# How Json Result Get to another Class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to The Jsonresult load to another class

```
func getData(username:NSString) {



    let URL = NSURL(string:  (Config.apiUrl as String)+"/apiname?user_email=\(username)")
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!)
    print(req)
   // let connection : NSURLConnection! = NSURLConnection(request: req, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: response)

}


func response(res: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?){


    if (error != nil) {

    }

    var err: NSError
          do{

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))


        guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = jsonResult as? NSDictionary else {
            print("Not a Dictionary")

            // put in function
            return
        }

      //  print(TableData)

        let status: String! = jsonResult["message"] as! NSString as String


        if(status == "success"){

            let json_candid_email = jsonResult["candid_email"] as? String
        }

        else{



            print("NO Details")
        }
    }
    catch let JSONError as NSError {
        print("\(JSONError)")
    }


}
```

I parse the json value in login page how to pass inside class

Comment: inside what class?

Comment: i want load the json api values to anther view controller page

Comment: create an instance of another view controller, create a property for that view controller and set the values to the property